# load requirejs via javascript

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Quick question, can I inject requirejs library from javascript .
Here what I am trying to achieve is create an RequireJs app and inject it by lets say `main.js`

In main.js

- It loads the requirejs library. Creates its scope.
- define the config in the newly created requirejs scope.

In Html all I need to add is

```
<script src="main.js:></script>
```

I am trying this approach because the page on which I am trying to load requirejs app already running other requirejs app with lower version. I am using the latest version. So that both apps doesn't conflict.

Answer (score 0):

If the app using the older version is instantiated like this

```
<script data-main="js/app.js" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

To run under the newer version you might try

```
<script data-main="js/main.js" src="js/v2_1/require.js"></script>
```

Which, if it works, should be less trouble than injecting it via some other scheme.